# exclude days from another table using two dates inside function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I created a stored procedures to calculate the vacation days for employees, and I need to remove all holidays which is exist in another table.

Here is my function for removing Fridays from the vacation duration :

```
ALTER FUNCTION [VSRC].[CalculateNumberOFWorkDays] 
   (@StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
   SET @StartDate = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @StartDate), 0) 
   SET @EndDate = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @EndDate), 0)

   DECLARE @WORKDAYS INT
   SELECT @WORKDAYS = (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
                      - (DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 1)
                      - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Friday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                      - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Friday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   RETURN @WORKDAYS
END
```

I am sending the `startdate` and `enddate` as parameters to the function and it will return total number of vacation days without Fridays, now I need to exclude all dates which is exist in in this table :

```
CREATE TABLE [VSRC].[tbHolydays]
(
    [HolydayID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [HolydayName] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [HolydayDate] [date] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_tbHolydays] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([HolydayID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Shouldn't you relate the person's religion to the religion of the holy day?

Comment: no , it's not required on this system.

Comment: As an aside, can you move this kind of rule up in to a business layer? If so this would make testing easier and the logic more resilient and adaptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code to:

```
SELECT @WORKDAYS =  (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
                    -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 1)
                    -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Friday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                    -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Friday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                    -(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [VSRC].[tbHolydays] WHERE HolydayDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
```